# How do I connect Project2 with Project1 stored in the existing github repository?

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I saved the boardProject1 on github without intellij integration.
Now I want to link intellij and github. How do I connect boardProject2 with boardProject1 stored in the existing github repository?

Comment: Just pull boardProject1 to the local computer and connect it to boardProject2 as module dependency: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html